# Sage implementation for discrete–time dynamical system

Tags: python, algorithm, sage

```
x1=18;x2 = 10

f1_0=(40)*x1*(100000-x1-x2)-x1;k1_0=f1_0+x1;k1_0.n()

f2_0=(1/3)*x1;k2_0=f2_0+x2;k2_0.n()

######################################################

x1=k1_0.n();x2=k2_0.n()

f1_1=(40)*x1*(100000-x1-x2)-x1;k1_1=f1_1+x1;k1_1.n()

f2_1=(1/3)*x1;k2_1=f2_1+x2;k2_1.n()

######################################################

x1=k1_1.n();x2=k2_1.n()

f1_2=(40)*x1*(100000-x1-x2)-x1;k1_2=f1_2+x1;k1_2.n()

f2_2=(1/3)*x1;k2_2=f2_2+x2;k2_2.n()
```

So, as you see that I have initial values for `x1` and `x2` then pluged it in the functions `f1` and `f2`, then I called a new variable `k1` which is just `f1+x1` and I have done the same thing for `f2`. Then, my resulted `k1` and `k2` become the new values for `x1` and `x2`, and so on. I want to do that several times, but I feel a bit stupid not having a for loop do that for `N` number of iteration. I am trying to do that in Sage. I looked up for some coding in Sage such using Newton's method. But I see that all them using a single variable in their programming. Would someone get me starting on the code for this problem.

Comment: What is `-*x1`?  You can't subtract and multiply at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In principle, you just rename things.  Here I've replaced `-*x1` with `-x1`, though I don't think this is right based on the numbers I'm getting.

```
x1=18;x2 = 10
for i in range(10):
    f1=(40)*x1*(100000-x1-x2)-x1
    k1=f1+x1
    f2=(1/3)*x1
    k2=f2+x2
    print k1, k2
    x1=k1.n()
    x2=k2.n()
```

Comment: Great news!  If this answered your question, then be sure to click the check mark so that others know this solved it - and get a Python tutorial for yourself, that will really pay off for you, I think!

Comment: I did that. would you have any idea how would I have all my x1's in a list so I would be able to plot them and the same thing for x2's.

Comment: There are lots of question on Stackoverflow which can help you with that - look for how to create a Python list and append things to it!  Like I said, a good Python tutorial will be very helpful for you.  Hint: `points(zip(list1,list2))` once you have made your lists of x1 and x2 values.